# Fan will not oscillate

Tags: fans

I have a pedestal fan that I have had for a while and recently stopped oscillating. what is the fix for this? would it make more financial sense to just buy a new one?

Comment: Most of the parts in these are plastic if the gears are worn out and you want it to oscillate probably time for a new one. I have pulled these apart and lubed the bearings but not much on the gear for the oscillating part.

Comment: Small appliance repair is off-topic here, as are financial questions. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ed Beal, if the plastic gears are stripped, there is no practical way to replace them. But did you check to see if there is a plunger that is INTENDED to engage / disengage the oscillation? Some designs have that, some don't. On those that do, it's usually set up that you pull UP to engage the oscillation, push DOWN to disengage it. So when moving the fan, if you accidentally pushed the plunger down, you inadvertently turned off the oscillation. In the image below, the oscilation plunger is the device on the left.
[image]